# Check if a user is a member of SharePoint group JS REST API using async await

Tags: javascript, jsom

How can I check if the current user is a member of a specific SP Group using REST API and async/await?

`_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/sitegroups/getbyname('" + grpName + "')/CanCurrentUserViewMembership";`

here's my code but it doesn't work and want to use async/await but how?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(showAlert, "sp.js");
});

function showAlert() {

    if(isMember('Viewers') && !isMember('Owners'))
        alert('Viewers'); //current user is part of the Viewers group
}

function isMember(grpName) {
    var _ismember = false;
    var siteUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/sitegroups/getbyname('" + grpName + "')/CanCurrentUserViewMembership";

    $.ajax({
        url: siteUrl,
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"},
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            if(data.d.CanCurrentUserViewMembership != null) {
                return data.d.CanCurrentUserViewMembership;

            }   
        },
        error: function (error) {}
    });
}
```

UPDATE: ok so I managed to convert this to async/await, my next question is, how can I compare the two data returned (true/false) by the API?

```
isMember('Viewers')
        .then(data => console.log(data.d.CanCurrentUserViewMembership + ' viewers'))
        .then(
            isMember('Owners')
            .then(data => console.log(data.d.CanCurrentUserViewMembership + ' owners')))
```

what I want to do is if Viewers = true; and Owners = false, then I will show an alert (because I want to only show an alert if the user is a member of the Viewers group only, but if a user is a member of Viewers AND Owners, no alert should be shown)

Comment: If group do not have settings that everyone can see the members, then if your user is not member, code will give you error. Instead try to get the user's group and in loop or filter check if your required group is there.

Comment: yes i've set this up already, i just need to have the code for async / await thanks

Comment: it seems it always returns true

Comment: Thanks this one works with Membership view able: Everyone. _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/sitegroups/getByName('"+ groupName +"')/Users?$filter=Id eq " + _spPageContextInfo.userId,

Answer (score 3):

If I am not wrong, you want to call the `isMember` function twice and parallely. After both call executes, you want to check if user's membership.

**Solution**:

1. If you are using **jQuery**:

   You can use `jQuery.when()`.

   **Reference**: [jQuery.when()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/)
2. If you are using **Angular JS**:

   You can use `$q.all()`.

   **Reference**: [$q.all()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#all)

---

**Update**: Use below code to check the membership of SharePoint group:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    isMember("Test Group");
});

function isMember(groupName){
    $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/sitegroups/getByName('"+ groupName +"')/Users?$filter=Id eq " + _spPageContextInfo.userId,
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        success: function(data){
            if(data.d.results[0] != undefined){
                // Exist in group
            }
            else
            {
                // Does not exist
            }
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

**Note**:

If **Who can view the membership of the group?** in group settings is set to **Everyone** then `CanCurrentUserViewMembership` will always return true.

Comment: yes, i've already fixed that using async/await. now my problem is `CanCurrentUserViewMembership ` always returns true

Comment: Use above code to check the membership of group. Keep everyone in who can view the membership of group.

Comment: Does this answers your question?

Comment: It did help me. +1 :)

Comment: If "who can view the membership of the group?" in group settings is set to "Everyone" then `CanCurrentUserViewMembership` will always return true. So use updated code in my answer to check the current user group membership.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of looking at the group's members, check the current user's groups instead.  This way you can keep the group locked down and not worry about someone 'peeking':

```
/_api/web/currentuser/?$expand=groups
```

Then iterate through the results and check if that group returns.