# Check if user belongs to a SharePoint group using REST API via OData

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-rest-api, groups, 2019

I am currently trying to write a OData query to determine if the current user belongs to a particular SharePoint group on SharePoint 2019 Server.

**Solution #1:** Retrieve the user's groups, then determine if group is part of user properties
URL: `https://test.com/_api/Web/CurrentUser/Groups`

Here is the XML generated (I have removed the other nodes I do not need from the sample below)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<feed xml:base="https://test.com">
    <id>123213123</id>
    <entry>
        <id>https://test.com</id>
        <content type="application/xml">
            <m:properties>
                <d:LoginName>Visitors</d:LoginName>
                <d:Title>Visitors</d:Title>
            </m:properties>
        </content>
    </entry>
        <entry>
        <id>https://test.com</id>
        <content type="application/xml">
            <m:properties>
                <d:LoginName>Visitors 2</d:LoginName>
                <d:Title>Visitors 2</d:Title>
            </m:properties>
        </content>
    </entry>
</feed>
```

**Solution #2:** Get SharePoint group and determine if user is in the group.

URL: `https://test.com/_api/Web/SiteGroups/GetByName('Visitors 2')`

Sample XML Generated:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <feed xml:base="https://test.com">
        <id>313213123</id>
        <entry>
            <id>https://test.com/_api/Web/GetUserById(161)</id>
            <category term="SP.User" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme"/>
            <link rel="edit" href="Web/GetUserById(161)"/>
            <title/>
            <author>
                <name/>
            </author>
            <content type="application/xml">
                <m:properties>
                    <d:LoginName>i:0e.t|test.com|user_1</d:LoginName>
                    <d:Title>user_1</d:Title>
                    <d:Email>user_1@test.com</d:Email>
                </m:properties>
            </content>
        </entry>
        <entry>
            <id>https://test.com/_api/Web/GetUserById(162)</id>
            <category term="SP.User" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme"/>
            <link rel="edit" href="Web/GetUserById(162)"/>
            <title/>
            <author>
                <name/>
            </author>
            <content type="application/xml">
                <m:properties>
                    <d:LoginName>i:0e.t|test.com|user_2</d:LoginName>
                    <d:Title>user_2</d:Title>
                    <d:Email>user_2@test.com</d:Email>
                </m:properties>
            </content>
        </entry>
    </feed>
```

Appreciate if someone can guide me on the **OData query** for either of the above, as I can't seem to get it right.

Alternatively, also welcoming any other suggestions on how I can accomplish the above.

Comment: What is the problem here exactly?

Comment: You can add filter query based on group name like: `/_api/web/currentuser/groups?$select=Title&$filter=Title eq 'Visitors 2'`. Let me know if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Also, check this: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/261025/check-if-a-user-is-a-member-of-sharepoint-group-js-rest-api-using-async-await

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to add filter query based on group name, use SharePoint REST API endpoint like:

```
/_api/web/currentuser/groups?$select=Title&$filter=Title eq 'Visitors 2'
```

**Example**:

Here is the complete HTML and JavaScript code to check the group membership of currently logged in user based on group name:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/SPConnect/SiteAssets/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" onclick="checkUserGroupMembership('Flow Owners')"> Check User Group Membership </button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkUserGroupMembership(groupName) {
        var groupsEndpoint = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/currentuser/groups?$select=Title&$filter=Title eq '" + groupName + "'";

        $.ajax({
            url: groupsEndpoint,
            type: "GET",
            headers: {
                "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
                "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose"
            },
            success: function (data) {                
                //console.log(data);
                if(data.d.results.length > 0) {
                    alert('User is member of the group: ' + groupName)
                }
            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

**Output**:

[image]

**Additional Reference**: [Check if a user is a member of SharePoint group JS REST API using async await](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/261025/check-if-a-user-is-a-member-of-sharepoint-group-js-rest-api-using-async-await)