# Check if user has custom permission level using REST API via OData

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, 2019, odata

I am currently have a **custom permission level** called 'Special Permission'.

In my webpart, I want to detect if the *current user is part of any SharePoint group that has 'Special Permission'*, and achieve this via REST API OData query.

Is there anyway to do this?
I do not see any such values listed `via /_api/Web/CurrentUser`

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: Are you trying to check if user is member of a group (where you know the name of group) or you only know the name of custom permission level?

Comment: @GaneshSanap-MVP Only the name of custom permission level. Thanks

Comment: I think it is not possible using single API call. First you will have to fetch the group names with permission level using API call: `_api/Web/RoleAssignments?$expand=Member,RoleDefinitionBindings` then you can check if user belongs to any of those groups by following: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/309931/check-if-user-belongs-to-a-sharepoint-group-using-rest-api-via-odata/309932#309932. Let me know if this works for you.